# Как сделать 2 фоновых картинки?

Tags: изображения, css

Ест 2 фоновые картинки. Нужно 1 расположить сверху, вторую снизу, причем с отступами сверху/снизу соответственно.
Можно ли это сделать все в одном селекторе body? Пробовал, получилось что вставлялось только 1.

Так же, решил оставить верхний фон в боди, а нижний закинуть через другой тег, расположив его снизу. Но, почему то он покрывает другие элементы. если поставить прозрачность, то показывается лишь текст,а другие элементы все равно будут за ним. Если поставить отрицательный з-индекс, то он вообще исчезает за боди.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
background:url(../img/1.png) top right(положение/отступы) no-repeat,
           url(../img/2.png) 100px 200px(положение/отступы) no-repeat;
```

Порядок зависит от последовательности. Первое что снизу, следующее что сверху и так далее.
Если говорим про старые IE, то можно скачать и подключить [css3pie](http://css3pie.com) и добавить дополнительный параметр:

```
-pie-background:url(../img/1.png) top right(положение/отступы) no-repeat,
                url(../img/2.png) 100px 200px(положение/отступы) no-repeat;
```

Если сразу не появится, посмотрите по позиционированию в IE, добавить position:relative; или position:repative; z-index:1;

Comment: Кстати, давно использовал `css3pie` и никогда не знал, что двойной background он тоже имитирует, вместо этого делал еще один блок для другого фона. Спасибо вам!

Comment: Пожалуйста, будут вопросы, обращайтесь, чем смогу, как говорится.

Comment: Что-то не работает...
  background: #062C47 url('../images/bg_top.png') 0 132px repeat-x,
              #062C47 url('../images/bg_btm.png') 0 100% repeat-x;
Вместо фона - стандартный белый.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shanhaichik/gBR9P/
Вот пример
Посмотрите свое позиционирование.

Answer (score 1):

Я может не совсем понял вопрос, но почему вы не используете `CSS`-свойство background для `body`? Тут два варианта:

1. Если кроссбраузерность не критична, то можно использовать [множественный бэкграунд](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/).
   Для случая, если браузер не понимает таких множественных бэкграундов, я бы загрузил одну из двух картинок уже обычным, не множественным бэкграундом. Если сами картинки, позволяют, конечно.
2. Если кроссбраузерность важна, то первый бэкграунд тегу `body`, второй бэкграунд дополнительному `div`-у вложенному сразу в `body`.

Comment: Делал по 2 варианту, возникла ситуация когда фон скрывает за собой все, если добавить прозрачность то будет показан лишь текст. То есть свойства следующие были:

  background: #062C47 url('../images/bg_btm.png') repeat-x;
  height: 477px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: -460 0 -30px 0;
  opacity: 1;
  display: none;

Answer (score 1):

На [htmlbook](http://htmlbook.ru/faq/kak-dobavit-dve-fonovye-kartinki-na-veb-stranitsu) есть целая статья по это

Answer (score 0):

Здравствуйте, а если так.

```
<img src='1.jpg' alt='' style='position:fixed;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:50%;'/>
<img src='2.jpg' alt='' style='position:fixed;bottom:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:50%;'/>
```

Вставляем после body.

Answer (score 0):

Передо мной стояла задача разместить 2 изображения в фоне и одному из них задать прозрачность.

Вот решение:

1. в обертку блока вставляем картинку которая будет сверху и у нее будет прозрачность
2. Картинку которая будет снизу добавляем через css
3. У всех блоков, которые будут располагаться поверх этого фона должен быть:

position: relative;
z-index: 2;

```css
.signup-wrapper {
  height: 490px;
  background: url('../img/Signup/Layer 5.png');
  position: relative;
}

.signup-wrapper__background {
  opacity: 0.75;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="signup-wrapper">
  <img src="../img/Signup/Newsletter section.png" class="signup-wrapper__background">
</div>
```