# Два фоновых изображения background-image

Tags: изображения, html, css

Возможно ли для кнопки/div'а сделать два фоновых изображения?
Т.е. в первом я хочу использовать градиент и повторять его по горизонтали, а во втором хочу использовать иконку без повторения, выравненную по правому краю.

Comment: Не удержусь напомнить про «[принцип цикады](http://habrahabr.ru/post/117160/)» применительно к веб-дизайну.

Answer (score 1):

Учим [два фона и больше](http://htmlbook.ru/blog/dva-fona-i-bolshe). [Как добавить два фоновых изображения к одному элементу?](http://htmlbook.ru/faq/kak-dobavit-dva-fonovykh-izobrazheniya-k-odnomu-elementu)

Поиск по форуму нужно юзать: [как сделать 2 фоновых картинки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/145990/css-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-2-%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B8) Там узнаете отличный способ для IE.